# Using mahout for anomaly detection

Tags: mahout

Can anyone please help me in letting me know if there is any good library for doing anomaly detection using mahout?

Comment: This is off-topic, since it's asking for a library recommendation.

Comment: i am pretty new to machine learning and i have a requirement of doing anomaly detection using mahout. so wanted to know as to what library or algorithm suites best for anomaly detection

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other algorithms Mahout has an OnlineSummarizer which uses the [T-Digest](https://github.com/tdunning/t-digest) algorithm to compute online descriptive statistics.  For an example of using The OnlineSummarizer for anomaly detection please see: [Strata 2014-anomaly-detection](http://www.slideshare.net/tdunning/strata-2014-anomaly-detection).